# Better way to set LI width in JSP / JSTL

Tags: css, jsp, dynamic, web

I have a UL in which I have 6 LI. I want to set a different width of each LI. I am using server side coding using JSP. I have a variable set which contains an array of 6 numbers. I want to assign those number as width % to the LI elements. The only way I can see doing is :

```
<li style="width:<c:out value="${number}"/>%;">hello</li>
```

This seems a bit lame. Is there a way in which I can dynamically set the width of an LI element using JSTL (and no client side tech like javascript / jquery).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do it like this :

```
<li style="width:${number}%;">hello</li>
```

The usage of `c:out` is useful to escape XML, for example if `number` content is :

```
<ul></ul>
```

the output will be

```
&lt;ul&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;
```

**More info :**

- [JSTL c:out](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/out.html)

Comment: yeah that makes sense. What would the purpose of c:out be then ? Everything that you can <c:out value=${somethign}> you can do ${something}

Comment: Ok, I already like your answer. Thanks. But just confirming, there is no other way you think I can " Is there a way in which I can dynamically set the width of an LI element using JSTL (and no client side tech like javascript / jquery)." ? Maybe using CSS3 or something

Comment: The other way will be in CSS but since I don't know how exacly you want to assign widths (what is the pattern), I can't help. Maybe you can improve your question and show the result you are expecting ie.: the full UL.

Answer (score 1):

Nice idea, @Alexandre Lavoie.

Personally, server-side dynamic CSS makes my head hurt, but there you go:

```
<head>
<style>
li
{
width: ${number}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li>hello</li>
</ul>
</body>
```